# AWS Cognito for Slack Clone

Tags: amazon-cognito, usergroups, aws-userpools

**I'm not actually trying to clone slack, it's just an analogy**

I'm trying to understand how to manage users who have their own account context but can also have a one-to-many context with organizations.

Since I'll have more than 25 organizations user groups don't seem to make sense -- and I'll want users to all be admins in their private context but have assignable roles within the orgs they're members of.

My thought for this was to have a general cognito pool that all users are members of but then federate them into organization's user pools also -- this seems wasteful since I'll be duplicating (or more) all users in different pools, but I'm not sure what other options exist at scale.

This is *similar* to a slack context

Any insights as to how you'd create pool structures to mirror their configuration would be really helpful.

Comment: This is very interesting! What does it mean for a user to have More Than One organization in Slack, in your view? Personally, I don't see user's as having more than one org. I see shared spaces between users in different orgs. I see the slack app which can hold an account configuration for multiple accounts. But I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that if you add an account to Slack on your desktop, it is immediately available as an option to add on your phone. So there is even another layer of accounts at play, but I'm not exactly sure how that's being handled, because if they use some sort of "related account", that feels like a security issue. I was thinking that the Google or Apple account might store some of that, but maybe not, because the desktop app shouldn't have any connection to those, per se.